# $A(A^{17}-cI)=0$, what is $c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, and there are $\det(A)=6$ and $A(A^{17}-cI)=0$, what is $c$?

---

My solution:

$$\det (A(A^{17}-cI))= \det(A)\cdot\det(A^{17}-cI)=0,$$

which means that

$$\det(A^{17}-cI)=0,$$

then, we can say that $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{17}$. W.L.G, we assume that $A^{17}$ has three identical eigenvalues, there is
$$c=6^{17/3}.$$ I think this is not rigorous.

Comment: If $A(A^{17} - cI) = 0$, then $A^{18} = cA$. In particular, their determinants must be the same.

Comment: The use of WLG here is a bit shady: it is not a priori clear that it does make no difference whether there are multiple different eigenvalues or not. However, perhaps instead of appealing to no loss of generality we can actually prove that in these circumstances the eigenvalues *must* be the same? Of course you don't need it if you use Jeroen's incredibly clever argument, but I am still curious if this can be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible we obtain $A^{17}=cI_3$. Taking determinants we have
$$
6^{17}=\det(A)^{17}=\det(A^{17})=\det(cI_3)=c^3.
$$